# Is it necessary to optimize pageview with large amount of pages in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, optimization

I have a `PageView` with a large amount of pages in my app. Each of the pages is very complex with a `PageView` and its own pages.

I'm new to Flutter and my first hunch is that it needs optimization. So within the `build()` function of the outmost `PageView` I check the index and only make full page for current, previous and the next page(I guess swipe animation needs current page and the page next to it built ahead). For other pages I just give it an empty `Container()`.

Is this necessary and the right thing to do? I felt this is an obvious optimization that the Flutter should do, but I can't find any related discussion online. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: PageView`s itemBuilder is only calling for an index when it's really needed and you don't need to do anything else

Comment: @Amir_P Thank you very much! I just tried disabling my own optimization, even though I make all pages every time the `build()` of the outmost `PageView` is called, the `build()` functions of each page is called only when it's necessary automatically. You should put your reply as a answer so I can make it the right answer to this question. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter's `PageView` is lazily calling `itemBuilder` you provided. For an index it's called only when the page is really needed and you don't need to do anything more. But for further improvements you can make your view hierarchy simpler and prevent unnecessary build method calls. [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices) you can read more about Performance best practices.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. `ListView`, `GridView`, and widgets alike are already optimized to build and render only what is needed in the moment. You get a hint of that in the PageView.builder description :

> Creates a scrollable list that works page by page using widgets that
> are **created on demand**

I think the difference between a regular `PageView` and a `PageView.builder` is that `PageView` initializes all children at startup, while `PageView.builder` are initialized lazily.